# Как добавить переменную для просмотра в режиме отладки в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как добавить свою переменную для просмотра в режиме отладки в IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4):

Для этого нужно нажать на кнопку <kbd>New Watch (Insert)</kbd> на панели **Variables** и ввести имя переменной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Также работает двойной клик на пустом месте в списке Watches и Alt+Insert при фокусе на Watches. Фокус на Watches можно установить кликнув по панели или комбинацией клавиш Alt+5. Учитесь пользоваться горячими клавишами, при постоянной работе в IDE они сэкономят вам кучу времени, которое вы тратите на перенос руки с клавиатуры на мышь и обратно.